# How to read janusgraph vertexid from Cassandra db

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, janusgraph

I have a janusgraph database that uses Cassandra and ElasticSearch.
The database is huge and I need a way to traverse through all the vertexes of the janusgraph for specific use case.

I have tried writing a Spark job using the SparkGraphComputer, but even that times out.

I am trying to check if Spark Cassandra connector can be used to traverse through the data. Is there any way which can be used to get all the vertex ids for Cassandra directly using the *janusgraph_ids* table or the *edgestore* table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo-b4P1kHu8

Easiest known workaround is to keep a table with vertex id's outside janusgraph (e.g. by updating it during JG ingests) and using this table to do OLTP requests to JanusGraph during spark jobs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! But I am still not sure, how to handle the existing data in the janusgraph db.

Comment: Did you really try SparkGraphComputer with just g.V().id() ? Without shuffling steps there is no need for spark to have the entire graph int memory and the query should be simply handled partition by partition without timeouts.

Comment: I did try something similar, even that requires huge memory for spark to work. As the data is continuously, not sure how scalable is that.